# OpenLayers 4.2 - Changing the interaction geometry type from polygon to multipolygon

Tags: polygon, openlayers, geometry, well-known-text, format

I would like to make a selection with DragBox interaction and get the geometry type to **Multipolygon**.

Right now I'm getting a **Polygon** type back :

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-3, 48]),
        zoom: 7
    }), 
});

var select = new ol.interaction.Select();

var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly });

dragBox.on('boxend', function() {
    var geom = dragBox.getGeometry();
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();
    var wktRepresentation  = format.writeGeometry(geom);

    console.log("wktRepresentation: " + wktRepresentation); 
});
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is because `dragBox.getGeometry()` returns **bbox** geometry. You should get geometry from features that intersect with **bbox**. Lets suppose that geojson file that is loaded have both *polygon* and *multipolygon* geometry type. The function in this case for '`bboxend`' event is as follow.

```
  var selectedMultiPolygon;
dragBox.on('boxend', function() {
    selectedMultiPolygon = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon();
    var extent = dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();
    source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent,
        function(feature) {
            //check geometry type
            if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'MultiPolygon') {
                var polygonsArray = feature.getGeometry().getPolygons();
                for (i = 0; i < polygonsArray.length; i++) {
                    selectedMultiPolygon.appendPolygon(polygonsArray[i]);
                }
            } else if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Polygon') {

            selectedMultiPolygon.appendPolygon(feature.getGeometry());
        }

        selectedFeatures.push(feature);

    });
console.log(selectedMultiPolygon);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3yqf78L/